# how to configure CID fonts for docsplit (ghostscript)?

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript, docsplit

I have guide reference in url below.
http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.06/Use.htm#CIDFonts

But I think I'm not following it correctlly.

What I'm trying to do is Convert Office files to Images using Docsplit.
But some characters(Korean&Chinese) are shown as question marks.

I assumed it has something to do with ghostscript, 
but having hard time, since I'm new to linux based solutions.

Can someone tell me command line by line guide on how to configure CID Fonts?

Comment: Currently using Cent OS 6 !

Comment: Version of *Ghostscript*.....

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ghostscript are you using ? If its CentOS then I suspect you are using an archaic version. First thing I would suggest is to upgrade to the latest version of Ghostscript.

After that I'd need a copy of the PostScript file (NOT the Office file) you are sending to Ghostscript, and the font(s) you are trying to use.

If you are using genuine CIDFonts, then this is trivially easy. However if, as is more likely, you are trying to use a TrueType font as a substitue fora CIDFont then the whoel problem becomes much harder.

Why can you not embed the fonts in the PostScript ? That would eliminate the problem altogether.